# What data type is GUID in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key, guid

How is GUID internally stored and compared by SQL (particularly MS SQL server 2008)? Is it a number or string? Also, is there a big performance hit when using GUID as primary key?

Besides the problem with clustering mentioned here: 
[What are the best practices for using a GUID as a primary key, specifically regarding performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938044/guid-as-primary-key-best-practices)

I think it should be 128bit number (as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/06/27/8659071.aspx)), but I cannot find mode details on how is it implemented in SQL server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945878/how-is-a-guid-actually-stored-and-sorted-compared-in-sql-server

Comment: Thanks, I have missed that somehow ... .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

16 bytes, exactly as the [GUID structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
typedef struct _GUID {
  DWORD Data1;
  WORD  Data2;
  WORD  Data3;
  BYTE  Data4[8];
} GUID;
```

Answer (score 19):

Performance wise, normal `GUID` is slower than `INT` in SQL Server

If you plan to use `GUID`, use `uniqueidentifier` instead of `varchar` as data type. Microsoft did not mention how they implement it, there is some speed optimization when you use `uniqueidentifier` as the data type.

To use `GUID` as primary key without sacrificing speed of integer, make the `GUID` value *sequential*. Define `uniqueidentifier` data type as PK, set the default to `NEWSEQUENTIALID()`.

See [NEWSEQUENTIALID (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql) for further details.

As to how sequential `GUID` values help performance, see [The Cost of GUIDs as Primary Keys](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25862).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use nvarchar(128).

The next-best option would be a binary(16) column:

standard GUIDs are exactly 16 bytes in length. 
If you must store it as a string, the length really comes down to how you choose to encode it. As hex (AKA base-16 encoding) without hyphens it would be 32 characters (two hex digits per byte).